# What does this function actually do?

Tags: swift

i am currently trying to do some self learning in swift just for my own interest. in the course i bought it says that we should create a function similar to this one in order to solve my problem. but I'm blankly staring trying to figure out what this function actually does?

```
func unknown() -> () -> Int {
  var x = 0
  let z: () -> Int = {
    x += 1
    return x
  }
  return z
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a function that returns another function which will return an integer that will be increased everytime you call it:

```
let afunc = unknown()
let value1 = afunc()  // 1
let value2 = afunc()  // 2
let value3 = afunc()  // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part of this is the return type.  `() -> Int` is a function that returns an `Int`, which means that `unknown` returns a function rather than something simple, like a number.

`z` is then a variable of that same type and is assigned a function definition to be returned.

If you assign the result of `unknown` to a variable, you can then invoke the returned function.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of a high order function is an interesting way of defining [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)). An infinite sequence-like class would've achieve the same thing, but with more verbosity:

```swift
class MySequence {
    private var x = 0
    
    func unknown() -> Int {
        x += 1
        return x
    }
}

var seq = MySequence()
let unknown = seq.unknown
print(unknown()) // 1
print(unknown()) // 2
print(unknown()) // 3
// ... and so on
```

The main difference between the class and the anonymous closure is the storage for `x`: the closure captures in due to using the variables within its body, while the class declares explicit storage for the property.

Some fancy stuff can result by using high order functions, like a generator for the Fibonacci numbers:

```swift
func fibonnaciSequence() -> () -> Int? {
    var a = 0, b = 1
    return { let c = a; a += b; b = c; return c }
}

let fibo = fibonnaciSequence()
while let f = fibo() {
    // this will print forever
    // actually not forever, it will stop at some point due to += overflowing
    print(f)
}
```